# Problem showing that a function is analytical

Tags: complex-analysis

Our lecturer gave us the following problem:

Let $u$ and $v$ be two harmonic functions defined on a domain $D\subset \mathbb{C}$. Define two new
functions:
$$U(x,y) = 2(u_x(x,y)u_y(x,y) + v_x(x,y)v_y(x,y))$$

$$V(x,y) = u^2_x(x,y)-u^2_y(x,y)+v^2_x(x,y)-v^2_y(x,y)$$

where $x+iy \in D$. Show that the function $g(z) = U(x,y)+iV(x,y)$, where $z = x+iy \in
D$, is analytic in $D$.

My first thought was to show that both U and V are harmonic by using the laplacian.

$U_x = 2(u_{xx}u_y + u_xu_{yx} + v_{xx}v_y + v_xv_{yx})$

$U_y = 2(u_{xy}u_y + u_xu_{yy} + v_{xy}v_y + v_xv_{xy})$

Now here is where I start having some problems: Trying to differentiate another time to check if $U_{xx} = -U_{yy}$.

$U_{xx} = 2(u_{xxx}u_y + u_{xx}u_{yx} + u_{xx}u_{yx} + u_xu_{yxx} + v_{xxx}v_y + v_{xx}v_{yx} + v_{xx}v_{yx} + v_xv_{yxx})$

$U_{yy} = 2(u_{xyy}u_y + u_{xy}u_{yy} + u_{xy}u_{yy} + u_xu_{yyy} + v_{xyy}v_y + v_{xy}v_{yy} + v_{xy}v_{xy} + v_xv_{xyy})$

Here is where I struggle to show that $U_{xx} = -U_{yy}$. Am I missing something or did I just go wrong somewhere?

Comment: I don't see how you get $U_x=-U_y$.  In $U_x$ the coefficient of $u_{xx}$ is $u_y$ and in $U_y$ the coefficient of $u_{yy}$ is $u_x$.  In any event, it might be easier to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Oh, shoot, you're right! I misread my own notes here. Good catch. And doesnt the Cauchy Riemann equations require the functions to be harmonic to be applicable? Which means I still have to prove harmonicity beforehand.

Comment: No, I don't think that's right.  Look at [Goursat's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Goursat's_theorem_and_its_generalizations)

Comment: Oh, alright! Thanks a bunch, that makes this easier, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tedious calculation we get
$$
V_x = 2(u_{xx}u_x-u_{yx}u_y+v_{xx}v_x-v_{yx}v_y)\\
V_y = 2(u_{xy}u_x+u_{yy}u_y+v_{xy}v_x-v_{yy}v_y)
$$
Apply what you got from the fact that both $u$ and $v$ are harmonic:
$$
V_x = 2(-u_{yy}u_x-u_{xy}u_y-v_{xx}v_x-v_{xy}v_y) = -U_y \\
V_y = 2(u_{xy}u_x-u_{xx}u_y+v_{xy}v_x-v_{xx}v_y) = U_x
$$
We may conclude that $U+iV$ is analytical using Cauchy-Riemann equations by the fact that $U$, $V$ are differentiable and $U_x=V_y$, $U_y=-V_x$ hold.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I could apply Cauchy-Riemann unless I proved harmonicity before.

Comment: @Max To convince you that you could just apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations, do a straightforward check.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Max You can show that if $u$, $v$ is a pair of differentiable functions that satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, then $u+iv$ is complex-differentiable.

Comment: Oh, alright! Thanks :)